# How to see what Observables are not completed while debugging

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs-observables

In an Angular app you might end up having quite a few Observables and you might forget to complete them when not needed anymore. Because of that they might trigger unexpectedly leading to unexpected side effects that are difficult to debug.

Is there a way to see at any moment during debugging all the Observables that are not completed? I am thinking of a DevTools tool.

Comment: How do you currently complete these observables?

Comment: I complete them either with take(1) or with takeUntil(destroy$) and some I do not complete, they stay subscribed forever

Comment: You can unsubscribe an Observable (in the ngOnDestroy for example). To do so you can either create a variable for each subscription or create a `const subs = new Subscription()` where you can add (`subs.add(obs$.subscribe(...))`) all subscriptions and unsubscribe (`subs.unsubscribe()`) only once (ngOnDestroy).

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is a memory profiler devtool. Memory -> take snapshot. do something that causes memory leaks, take another snapshot and compare them

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any obvious and simple way to do exactly what you're looking for.

However, since [RxJS 7.3](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#730-2021-07-28) `tap()` operator can handle apart from the three notification types three new event "subscribe", "unsubscribe" and "finalize" (basically the same as using `finalize()` operator). (the same functionality could be achieved using `defer()` and `finalize()` in RxJS versions < 7.3).

In your case you could listen to all "subscribe" and "unsubscribe" and if they're called the same number of times then you know that all subscriptions were unsubscribed either manually or the source completed/errored:

```
import { of, tap, delay } from 'rxjs';

let counter = 0;

const source$ = of('World')
  .pipe(
    delay(1000),
    tap({
      subscribe: () => console.log('Subscribers: ', ++counter),
      finalize: () => console.log('Subscribers: ', --counter),
    }),
  );
  
source$.subscribe();
source$.subscribe();
setTimeout(() => source$.subscribe(), 500);
setTimeout(() => source$.subscribe(), 2000);
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-oht1ex?devtoolsheight=60

If all subscribers get unsubscribed then you have to see `"Subscribers: 0"` in the console at the end.

Note, that `tap()` needs to be the last operator so the `finalize` handler is called after the delayed value is emitted.

Comment: ... and that's exactly why I'm handling both subscribe and finalize events as it's described in my answer

Comment: you can put this into component or service, depending on what you want to do